# Bell curve estimation

Tags: curves

I was asked the following:

> Estimate the values $\mu$ and $\sigma$, from the following diagram:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ [image]

I do get that the $\mu = 64$. I didn't know how to calculate the $\sigma$-value. The answer was $\sigma=1$.

Here is my question: Why? I have no idea how to get to that conclusion. Can you please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\fermi\pars{x,\sigma} \equiv 5\exp\pars{-\,{\pars{x - 64}^{2} \over 2\sigma^{2}}}}$
$$
\mbox{the minimum of}\
\,{\cal F}\pars{\sigma} \equiv \bracks{\fermi\pars{65,\sigma} - 3}^{2} + \fermi^{2}\pars{68,\sigma}
$$
is found with
$\ds{\color{#66f}{\large\sigma} \approx \color{#66f}{\large 0.989344}}$

> Here we can see a plot of $\ds{\,{\cal F}\pars{\sigma}}$ where $\ds{\sigma \in \bracks{0.8,1.2}}$:

[image]

With a 'drastic' $\ds{\fermi\pars{65,s} = 3}$, we'll get $\dsc{0.989347}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are supposed to use that about 68% of values drawn from a normal distribution are within one standard deviation $\sigma$ away from the mean; about 95% of the values lie within two standard deviations and about 99.7% are within three standard deviations. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Empirical_Rule.PNG for a link to a usefull picture.

Answer (score 1):

> *Here is my question: Why? I have no idea how to get to that conclusion.*

The overwhelming majority of the surface determined by the graphic of the Gaussian bell curve is supposed to be comprised in the interval $\mu\pm3\sigma$. That's what the $\sigma$ is for. Looking at your graphic, we notice that the overwhelming part of its entire area in comprised within the interval $64\pm3$. The conclusion should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, in a Normal distribution, $\mu$ is the intersection of the symmetry axis with $x$ axis and $\sigma$ is the distance between the symmetry axis and the inflection point on both sides of the Normal, which visually appears to be 1 (length of the side of the reference squares in the figure). See this site for details on how to find the inflection points ([link](https://www.thoughtco.com/inflection-points-of-a-normal-distribution-3126446)).